# Angular 6 custom validation to not allow space as the first character?

Tags: angular, angular6

I am using a reactive textbox, and I need few custom validations for that.

The input box cannot have a character starting with a blank space.

I am using the required validator to make it mandatory, but if I enter a space, it still considers it valid (which I don't want).

How can I fix this from occurring?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the help section on how to ask a good question, as this will help the community understand your issue and provide you with a good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 9):

You need to create a custom validator to handle this.

```
new FormControl(field.fieldValue || '', [Validators.required, this.noWhitespace])
```

Add noWhitespace method to your component/service

```
public noWhitespace(control: FormControl) {
    let isWhitespace = (control.value || '').trim().length === 0;
    let isValid = !isWhitespace;
    return isValid ? null : { 'whitespace': true }
}
```

and in the HTML

```
<div *ngIf="yourForm.hasError('whitespace')">Please enter valid text</div>
```

Comment: Legit. I'm thinking `const` instead of `let` and skip `isValid` altogether? Is the intermediary conversion to make it easy to understand? I'm not sure why `isValid` is needed.